# How to find out what root record is related to CKShare?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Simply I have a `CKShare` record. Having only this, I need to know what other root `CKRecord` is related with it.

Since there always need to be root record, I need to know it now. But can't see property in other place than in initializer.

```
public convenience init(rootRecord: CKRecord)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: isn't it a parent? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord/1640527-parent

Comment: No, it doesnt work;( `parent` is always *nil*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `CloudKit` operation: `CKFetchShareMetadataOperation`. This operation is initialized with an array of `CKShare().urls` and returns the corresponding array of `CKShareMetadata?`. The `CKShareMetadata` class contains the `rootRecordID: CKRecordID` and other interesting properties like the associated `share` and the `participantType: CKShareParticipantType`. The `participantType` can be used to tell if the client who performed the fetch is the owner of the share.

It also contains the optional `rootRecord: CKRecord?`. You can force 
fetch all root records by setting `shouldFetchRootRecord` to `true` on the `CKFetchShareMetadataOperation` operation instance before adding to a queue.